# MariaDB container_name does not seem to resolve and UnknownHostException is triggered when the API container try to connect to it

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm trying to dockerize a simple Spring Boot API and a MariaDB, but when I try to do a `docker-compose up -d` to get the project up, I get a UnknownHostException. When this error happens, the db container is neither up, which I don't understand because the API service has a depends_on of the MariaDB container. I've tried to get the db container up before with `docker-compose -up -d db`, and then `docker-compose up -d`, but I get the same error. The logs of the MariaDB container are ok, it is ready for connections.

Dockerfile for the API image

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17-slim
WORKDIR .
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "mariadb:10.5.8"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test-db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootdev
      MYSQL_USER: dev
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dev
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  testnetwork:
```

application.propperties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/test-db
spring.datasource.username=dev
spring.datasource.password=dev
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

More extended error logs:

```
#7 50.98 [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.555 s <<< FAILURE! -
 in com.test.project.TestProjectTests
#7 50.98 [ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.016 s  <<< ERROR!
#7 50.98 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
#7 50.98 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with na
me 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa
/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persisten
ce.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exc
eption is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execut
ion
#7 50.98 Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build H
ibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to 
open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
#7 50.98 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for 
DDL execution
#7 50.98 Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=db)(
port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:db, port:3306. db
#7 50.98 Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:db, port
:3306. db
#7 50.98 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
#7 50.98
#7 51.32 [INFO]
#7 51.32 [INFO] Results:
#7 51.32 [INFO]
#7 51.32 [ERROR] Errors:
#7 51.32 [ERROR]   TestProjectTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Appl...    
#7 51.32 [INFO]
#7 51.32 [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
#7 51.32 [INFO]
#7 51.33 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 51.33 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
#7 51.33 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 51.33 [INFO] Total time:  49.092 s
#7 51.33 [INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-15T11:58:42Z
#7 51.33 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 51.33 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (defa
ult-test) on project test-project: There are test failures.
#7 51.33 [ERROR]
#7 51.33 [ERROR] Please refer to /target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
#7 51.33 [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date]
.dumpstream.
#7 51.33 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
#7 51.33 [ERROR]
#7 51.33 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
#7 51.33 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
#7 51.33 [ERROR]
#7 51.33 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following
 articles:
#7 51.33 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn clean install]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : Build failed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: During build time, the other containers aren't available. It's only when everything is built that the db container is started.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the API Dockerfile as follows and the problem was solved:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
COPY target/tapas-finder-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /tapas-finder-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/tapas-finder-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I think the problem was some kind of incompatibility between the Spring Boot libraries versions and the maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17-slim image.